# How do I print out the sum of a list given certain constraints

Tags: python, list, dictionary, sum

I'm trying to print the sum of a list generated through raw_input.

The numbers in the list must be between 1 and 1000, inclusive. The length of the list must be below 1000.

here is my code thus far:

```
initial_list = raw_input()

integer= initial_list.split(' ') 
if len(integer) <= 1000:
    for i in integer: 
        if i >= 1 and i<=1000:
            actual_integer = map( int, integer)
            print sum(actual_integer)
```

This does not print anything. Any suggestions and/or alternatives?

Comment: Why do you have something called `integer` that's actually a list? And something called `initial_list` that's actually a string? And why are you testing e.g. `i >= 1` **before** converting it to an integer? Did you think about this at all while you were writing it?!

Comment: Your logic is all messed up. You are mapping your `integer` list to a list of int on each iteration of your `for i in integer` loop. Then you are printing the sum of all integers on each loop as well.

Comment: Is the input data all on one line, with each number separated from the next by a single space?

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your objective correctly, you've got all the right ideas, you just need to re-order your logic a little and make sure you are clear in your head about when you're dealing with a list of values and when you're dealing with a single value.

You may wish to consider your variable naming, too, as good names can help you keep track of whether the variable has a type with multiple values or single values.  I've updated your code with that in mind

```
initial_list = raw_input().split() # split(' ') works, but you don't actually need the ' ',
                                   # split() on its own does the same job here
if len(initial_list) <= 1000:
    actual_integers = map(int, initial_list) #Moved to here.  Note that
                                             #actual_integers is a list
                                             #so for the following comparison
                                             #you just want to look at the max
                                             #and min (individual values)
    if min(actual_integers) >= 1 and max(actual_integers) <= 1000:
        print sum(actual_integers)
    else:  #Just added two nice messages to the user if it doesn't print out.
        print 'integers must be in range 1-1000 inclusive'
else:
    print 'your list must have 1000 integers or fewer'
```

Answer (score 0):

This code here does what you need but there is no error checking.

```
initial_list = raw_input()  # there should be some prompt text

# no error checking
integer = initial_list.split(' ')
# no output for lists > 1000
if len(integer) <= 1000:
    print sum(filter(lambda i: 0 < i <= 1000, map(int, integer)))
```

The output

```
$ python test.py
1 2 3 1500 0
6
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, this maybe what you're looking for.

This code will prompt the input and append the input to the list `lst` until  `lst` will have 1000 elements. It will only take an input if the input is a number between 1 and 1000 and it will give you the `sum` after every input.

```
lst = []
while len(lst) <= 999:
    initial_list = raw_input('Input numbers between 1 and 1000:')
    if initial_list.isdigit() and int(initial_list) <= 1000 and int(initial_list) >= 1:
        lst.append(int(initial_list))
        print 'List:', lst #prints the list
        total = sum(lst)  
        print 'List Sum:', total #prints the list sum
    else:
        print 'Input must be numbers between 1 and 1000'
```

Output:

```
Input numbers between 1 and 1000:12
List: [12]
List Sum: 12
Input numbers between 1 and 1000:45
List: [12, 45]
List Sum: 57
Input numbers between 1 and 1000:156
List: [12, 45, 156]
List Sum: 213
Input numbers between 1 and 1000:256
List: [12, 45, 156, 256]
List Sum: 469
Input numbers between 1 and 1000:
```